# Is "Why Python's designer got rid of curly braces and Julia's designers brought them back? Could Julia work just as well without them?" too beginner?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, scope

During the process of joining the site I saw:

> New site doesn’t necessarily mean “beginner” questions

So I'd like to vet my question here first - is this too much of a beginner question?

One of the many notable features of Python over others is its designer's<sup>1</sup> choice for complete reliance on indenting for **loops and conditional statements**, and Python even has something to say about this:

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

This suggests to me that curly braces in other languages for those types of statements were unessential.

And yet Julia, a sort-of successor to Python for applications like computational science have chosen to return to the nest and *embraces the braces* so to speak.

Why were both of these design choices made - to get rid of then and then to put them back?

Are they somehow essential for Julia?

Or are they there simply for the "[Ahhhhhh effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936200)" - looks more like the other compiled languages to the reader?

---

<sup>1</sup>not a typo - singular, not plural

Comment: Would you be looking for stated rationale from the designers (which probably does exist) or for broader reasons why such choices might be made in languages generically? Is it specifically "why does *Julia* need these?", or something else? There is definitely an acceptable on-topic question in there, just maybe more than one. It's definitely not too much of a beginner question.

Comment: [The only Julia question so far](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/25/34) got closed, but since we're in Private Beta, everyone can cast close or reopen votes regardless of their rep.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I've asked at the limits of my abilities/knowledge - (just between you and me, don't tell anyone, I am not a designer of languages (humor)). Languages for which I can still remember having experience in are FORTRAN, C, Python and Julia (tiny bit). I don't have broader experience *that I can still remember* so I would not be sure how to ask a less specific question without the possibility of it going sideways.

Comment: I *think* that asking about both is probably too broad, but "why did Julia choose to use braces for blocks" is an empirically answerable question (I expect, I don't know the answer). That question could note that Python didn't have them and many Julia users came from there, so what benefits justified the unfamiliar change? We do have a question about merits of indentation syntax already, and some about specific language comparisons. "Why did Python choose indentation syntax" is also a fine question that will have word-of-god answers (it's not clear that "getting rid of them" was part of it!).

Answer (score 5):

Indentation vs. braces is one of those age-old programmer debates that almost everyone has an opinion on. We already have [a fairly big Q&A on the subject](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-indentation-for-code-blocks), so if you're looking for reasons why Julia *might* have decided not to use indentation for blocks, then the reasons given in that Q&A may be satisfactory to you (and your question might be taken as a duplicate of this one).

On the other hand, if you want to know specifically what the Julia designers have said about this decision (if anything), then that would be on-topic and not (currently) a duplicate. But then the question should make clear that you're looking for references to statements made by Julia's designers, rather than speculation. Similarly, you could ask about statements made by Python's designers on the subject, though that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: If looking for statements by Julia developers, most users are just as capable of searching for these online as any other, so the question of whether or not enough prior research was done, might apply.